# How to get a comprehensive list of apps installed on wear device?

Tags: wear-os

i'm trying to get a list of the applications installed on the wear device using

packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

But many apps are missing from that list (all motorola apps, SetAlarm, SetTimer,ShowAlarms)

Anybody know what i should do to get all of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because these apps are intended to be launched only with voice.
Here is how I get them in Wear Mini Launcher:

```
try {
            ApplicationInfo app = manager.getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.deskclock", 0);

            String name = manager.getApplicationLabel(app).toString();

            Intent intentAI = new Intent();
            intentAI.setPackage(app.packageName);
            List<ResolveInfo> listRI = manager.queryIntentActivities(intentAI, 0);

            // Launchable app
            if (listRI.size() > 0) {
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : listRI) {


                    if (name != null) {


                        //Do your stuff here

                    }
                }
            }


        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! unfortunately i can't vote, my reputation is too low :(